# Reshaping data in R to get tooltip for googleVis gvisLineChart

Tags: r, googlevis

In R I am trying to make a scatter type plot, using `googleVis - gvisLineChart`, to support string type data, which `gvisScatterChart` doesn't.

***The problem*** is getting the **tooltip** I want as well. I am sorry this is a little long, most of it is reproducible code, to easier see what I want.

Below is a minimal reproducible example of my data.

```
noD <- 5

data <- runif(noD, -27, -23)
date <- gsub("1","03/06/09",
        gsub("2","06/06/09",
        gsub("3","09/06/09",round(runif(noD,1,3)))))

dutdata <- gsub("1","M1",gsub("2","M2",round(runif(noD,1,2))))

dfin <- data.frame(date = date, dut = dutdata, test = data)

dfin
#      date dut      test
#1 06/06/09  M2 -26.74390
#2 06/06/09  M1 -23.87237
#3 06/06/09  M1 -26.28179
#4 03/06/09  M1 -23.21293
#5 06/06/09  M1 -26.44278
```

So, I wanna create a `gvisLineChart`, where the x-axis is the date, y-axis is the test, and the tooltip is the dut. I can split the data according to the date, and reshape the test data to get what I want:

```
cbind.fill <- function(...){
  nm <- list(...) 
  nm<-lapply(nm, as.matrix)
  n <- max(sapply(nm, nrow)) 
  do.call(cbind, lapply(nm, function (x) 
          rbind(x, matrix(, n-nrow(x), ncol(x))))) 
}

datain <- data.frame(xdata = sort(unique(dfin$dut)),
                     ydata = t(do.call(cbind.fill,
                               lapply(split(dfin,dfin$dut),
                                        "[",c("test")))),
                      row.names = NULL)
datain
#     xdata   ydata.2   ydata.3   ydata.4   ydata.5
#1 03/06/09 -23.87237 -26.28179 -23.21293 -26.44278
#2 06/06/09 -26.74390        NA        NA        NA
```

Putting datain into `gvisLineChart` will give me the desired plot.

```
require('googleVis')
chart <- gvisLineChart(datain,
                   options=list(legend="none",
                                lineWidth=0,
                                pointSize=8,
                                width=400, 
                                height=400,
                                chartArea="{width:'80%',height:'80%'}",
                                axisTitlesPosition = 'out'),
                   chartid="customplot")

plot(chart)
```

## The problem:

Now I want to add a custom tooltip to this, providing the dut, corresponding to the data plotted. Normally this can be added by adding columns with `xx.html.tooltip`

Meaning I would have to reshape my data to look like below:

```
#     xdata   ydata.2   ydata.2.html.tooltip     ydata.3    ydata.3.html.tooltip   ...
#1 03/06/09 -23.87237                   "M1"   -26.28179                    "M1" 
#2 06/06/09 -26.74390                   "M2"          NA                      NA   ...
```

But I have absolutely no clue as how to come about this. Any suggestions, ideas or anything is very welcome!

Comment: It turns out that the above described solution to the tooltip doesn't work, as `gvisLineChart` doesn't support this... At least so it seems.